# Is there an option for a semitransparent text background in Google Drawings?

Tags: google-drawings

I am making announcements in Google Drawings and the text isn't as visible as I want.

Is there a way to make the text background color semitransparent?

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the drawing and select Background. On the menu that pops-up select the Custom option. On the dialog box that pops open choose the color and the transparency using the sliders on the right.

[image]

[image]